# Correct password fails to login (login loop) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, password, login-screen

I know this question asked so many times before but none of the solutions worked for me. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.5 (alongside Win10) when I type the correct pw it enters the login loop.

`journalctl` colored output: https://gist.github.com/ridvansumset/40e9223262361fa9590aa5e5bc5e10a6

The solutions I found on the web and tried are:

1- (at login screen) Ctrl+Alt+F3 then `chown username:username .Xauthority` then `mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak`

2- (at login screen) Ctrl+Alt+F3 then remove `lightdm` and reinstall it

3- Entering the recovery mode  then choosing dpkg then relogin

4- `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

5- etc/shadow file already exists.

Nothing works for me :(. Can someone please help? It's urgent

Comment: Also, how can I go back to login screen after entering terminal with CTRL+ALT+F3?

Comment: In 16.04, press CTRL+ALT+F7 to return to the login screen (or the desktop if you are already logged in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! I figured out what my problem is and now I can login!!! Here how I solved it:

Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 to enter terminal then login with your username and password.

Firstly, run `nano ~/bash_history`. This will show you the commands you used before. (Notice that the command at the top of the list is the oldest one). Then, look at your commands line by line, try to figure out which one can cause this problem. Pass unimportant commands like `cd` or `cat`. Try to focus on commands that makes effect on your system or environment. If you find anything, undo what you did.

In my case, it was `sudo nano etc/environment` command. When I inspected that file, there wasn't even any typo. But still, I removed all the lines
that I added before to revert my changes. Now it includes only `$PATH` variable which is:
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"`

Then I ran `source etc/environment`. After that I was able to login!

P.S: Never edit your `etc/environment` file. Instead use `export` command to set an environment variable. Besides, check if there is a typo in your `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` files, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Hell. I faced this too, and all I had to blame are unsigned Nvidia modules, or similar thing. So, I assume this isn't the first time you boot into Ubuntu since the first setup? And you got Nvidia drivers as well?

First of all, there has to be issues reported in your logs from

```
$ journalctl
```

If so, add to your post.

As a workaround, disable Secure Boot in your BIOS setup, if it's on (I mean, it MUST be on, because usually it blocks unsigned gfx driver from loading to kernel. This was my issue, however, since I left Ubuntu long time ago, I have different issue, for ex., on Arch, where desktop environment literally won't load up). Write me back with your results

Comment: I've been using ubuntu since may 2017. I had nvidia drivers but I used  `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` I don't know if I still have them. Secure boot was ON I disabled it from Windows BIOS. Then I tried to login and failed again. `journalctl` command's output is too big but I saw a line says _secureboot: secure boot could not be determined(mode 0)_.

Comment: I also tried to login in recovery mode but still no luck :/

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1451071
Also, it's obvious journalctl will output much info, but it's the system logs, it's supposed to be like that. I don't feel that the error message you shared is enough for clarifying. You could save all the error lines in some file and report back if possible like

    $ journalctl 2> ~/errors.txt

Comment: here is the colored output (if you open it in terminal) https://gist.github.com/ridvansumset/40e9223262361fa9590aa5e5bc5e10a6

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Problem description

Nvidia-396, which you have installed intently or unawarely auto-installed by other related package, such as swig, can not properly used in utuntu 16.04.

## 2. Solution

The best way to solve the problem would be ever find the miss-operation firstly. To do this, firstly, you need to check your command history by :

```
vi ~/.bash_history
```

and then search "sudo" keywords which indicate essential command, and find suspects. In my case, it is

```
 sudo install swig
```

Finally, revert it by :

```
sudo apt-get purge swig
```

*CAUTION : PLEASE NEVER DO*

> sudo apt-get upgrade

It will install newest package of your whole system which will include nividia-396